# Nginx won't serve built Vue App but other HTTP servers will

Tags: nginx, vue.js

I am trying to server static content via nginx that has been built from VueJS. For the seemingly simple and obvious setup, I am not able to route the static content via nginx. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

I have tested using a different HTTP server such as [Serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) this will work straight away.

mainsite.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/mainsite/dist;

    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;

    location / {
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            index index.html index.html;
    }
}
```